# How to fetch particular text from a string

Tags: c#

I have a string `"(zoneId==176)&&((startTime==100)&&(endTime==1200))"` from which i want to fetch the value of startTime and endTime in C#. How to do this i am new to c# programming that why i need some clue

Comment: that looks like a block of code, not a string.

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions - they're ideal for this sort of pattern matching.  If you get stuck, feel free to ask a question with information about what you've tried.

Comment: Take a look at `string.IndexOf` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `string.Substring` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look like a `String` but a block of code.  Assuming that is the value entered into your code, you could do the following:

```
var input = "(zoneId==176)&&((startTime==100)&&(endTime==1200))";
var time = input.Split(')');
var start = time.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("startTime")).Split('=')[2];
var end = time.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Contains("endTime")).Split('=')[2];
```

Your output would be as follows: `100` and `1200`

The above implementation works, but shouldn't be used for production purposes for an assortment of reasons.  You'll want to focus on:

- Substring
- Split
- Remove
- Regular Expressions

These are all essential to learning how to parse data and or any other form of *string manipulation*.  Hopefully this points you in the proper direction.

Another approach would be:

```
var input = "(zoneId==176)&&((startTime==100)&&(endTime==1200))";
var section = input.Split('=');
foreach(var region in section)
{
     var zone = region.Substring(0, region.Length);
     var number = zone.Where(d => char.IsDigit(d)).ToArray();
}
```